# Failed to load optimized model at path '~/WebPortalDB.momd/WebPortalDB 9.omo' and /Database.momd/OsiriXDB_DataModel.omo

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode-plugin

I'm stuck on this problem. Through XCode I created my plugin but once I run it, it opens Osirix without the created plugin giving me this error in the figure. How can I fix? The OsiriXDB_DataModel.omo file which fails to load is present in the given path.I am using Xcode version 9.2, Osirix Lite v.13.0.1 and OS 10.13.6. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJjrO.png)

I tried to run it on Horos but in that case it can't even open the program. I tried with other versions of Osirix but it keeps giving the same error. Do I need to change any parameters in the settings?Thank you very much!